# Connect Hyper-V VM from WSL (Ubuntu)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have created a VM on Hyper-V with 2 Network Adapters.

1. NAT switch [for static ip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network)
2. External Switch (for access internet)

From my command line I was able to connect to the VM with the Nat Switch IP
but from WSL Bash I was not able to connect with IP NatSwitch, but able to connect with ExternalSwitch IP.

Why?

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately this is the expected behavior. (As of 29/01/2021)

WSL2 uses Hyper-V Virtual Switch, *vEthernet (WSL)* virtual network adapter, that is providing *internal* type Hyper-V network that is only accessible from the VM and the Host. The Hyper-V machine has a different virtual network adapter e.g. *vEthernet (Default Switch)*. If that is set to internal that is a different NAT-ed network (subnet) not connected to the WSL one. It is like the Host having 3 NICs and one cable (Cable 1) going to WSL on a subnet that only exists on that adapter/cable and another cable (Cable2) going to Hyper-V guest with a very different subnet on that NIC.

[image]

On the other scenario the Hyper-V guest shares the subnet with the Host machine ("Same subnet as the 3rd cable/NIC.") so it is routed back to the VM. See red labels.

[image]

There is a workaround [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150) using port forwarding to Guest VM from WSL.

Answer (score 11):

I did this and it worked for me.

```
Get-NetIPInterface | where {$_.InterfaceAlias -eq 'vEthernet (WSL)' -or $_.InterfaceAlias -eq 'vEthernet (Default Switch)'} | Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled
```

Got it from [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-addressing-traffic-routing-issues/ba-p/1764074)